# How to set up Angular JS Maven project for UI and Spring Rest Maven project on server side?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, maven-3

I am newbie to Angular JS and also Spring REST API's. I am planning to develop 2 seperate applications, where 1st Project is UI which will be developed with Angular JS and 2nd project is Server side where it exposes REST calls to aforesaid UI project, for that I am planning to go for Spring REST framework. Both the projects will be using Maven build tool. Wanted to some inputs and tutorial links which really help me.

Thanks,

Comment: You could have a look at JHipster which you can use to quickly bootstrap a Spring, JPA, Angular etc. project. https://jhipster.github.io/

Comment: thanks AlanHay i will look into it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with an application generator that will set you up with an angularjs front end and a spring-boot backend. check out jhipster: http://jhipster.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to build the fronted (UI) with [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/) and manage dependencies with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). To call node/npm/gulp from Maven I recommend the [Frontend Maven Plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin). You can have a look at [Sagan](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/) (the codebase for the [spring.io](https://spring.io/) website) - they are doing the same (with Gradle instead of Maven).

Answer (score 0):

I have had same kind of case in one of my projects. The idea of this setup is that you have frontend and backend separated so that they would be easier to manage. You would transfer data from frontend to backend via REST web service.

Here's what you can do:

1. Setup three maven projects, where one is working as parent and two others as child projects. One of child projects is for backend (Java, Hibernate, Database connections, Spring and so on...). Other child project is for frontend.
2. Frontend project can be generated with Yeoman. This is nice tool where you can generate project structures. For example you can tell Yeoman to generate MEAN project and it will build MEAN project with required frameworks. There are many templates you can generate your project based on. Make sure that your project contains Grunt framework because there you can configure it to listen your backend project.
3. Once you have all your projects setup, then configure your Grunt file. You need to setup a proxy that listens your backend side (usually `http://localhost:port`). You need to make sure what's your backend server port.

With these steps you can now easily build your project and install whatever frameworks for frontend and backend. It will also be easy to manage, since you have moduled those projects.

Remember to deploy your backend maven to your server. Otherwise this setup won't work.